# Update/change Sony TV KD-55XE7005 to Android TV possible?

Tags: android-tv, smart-tv

I have a Sony TV KD-55XE7005 with the Firmware v8.905-1000. I do not exactly know what Firmware/OS it is (some SONY proprietary), but it is **NOT** Android TV. Other newer SONY TVs come with Android TV. **Can I change my TV to Android TV?**

I wish to do so that I can install applications, which is not possible with my TV. It comes with some apps, but no chance to add new ones.

Comment: Android and Android TV are no "universal OS" you can install yourself. You need and adapted version of Android[TV] for each device, therefore what you want is not possible until you or someone else adapts Android TV for your TV (assuming the hardware is powerful enough which is usually not the case).

Comment: Understood, good point. It was my hope that an adapted version exists, as SONY sells many TVs with Android TV. So I was vaguely hoping that my TV is also sold as a Android TV version and I somehow can patch it to that. However, most likely it is much easier to just buy a TV stick or a Raspberry Pi Android TV Box.